# Regex replace Windows line break characters

Tags: c#, regex

I have this bit of code, which is supposed to replace the Windows linebreak character (`\r\n`) with an empty character.

However, it does not seem to replace anything, as if I view the string after the regex expression is applied to it, the linebreak characters are still there.

```
    private void SetLocationsAddressOrGPSLocation(Location location, string locationString)
    {
        //Regex check for the characters a-z|A-Z.
        //Remove any \r\n characters (Windows Newline characters)
        locationString = Regex.Replace(locationString, @"[\\r\\n]", "");
        int test = Regex.Matches(locationString, @"[\\r\\n]").Count;    //Curiously, this outputs 0
        int characterCount = Regex.Matches(locationString,@"[a-zA-Z]").Count;
        //If there were characters, set the location's address to the locationString
        if (characterCount > 0)
        {
            location.address = locationString;
        }
        //Otherwise, set the location's coordinates to the locationString. 
        else
        {
            location.coordinates = locationString;
        }
    }   //End void SetLocationsAddressOrGPSLocation()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using verbatim string literal, thus `\\` is treated as a literal `\`.
So, your regex is actually matching `\`, `r` and `n`.
Use

```
locationString = Regex.Replace(locationString, @"[\r\n]+", "");
```

This `[\r\n]+` pattern will make sure you will remove each and every `\r` and `\n` symbol, and you won't have to worry if you have a mix of newline characters in your file. (Sometimes, I have both `\n` and `\r\n` endings in text files).